# Problemas para usar Semantic UI en un proyecto de React

Tags: jquery, nodejs, reactjs, semantic-ui

Soy nuevo en ***React*** y tengo problemas para usar funciones de semantic ui que utilizan jquery (cabe mencionar que puedo usar las clases css para darle estilo a los botones etc.)

Mi problema es que al presionar un botón quiero mostrar un modal de semantic pero la funcion en jquery me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi archivo **`index.js`** tengo los imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css';
```

Ya intente:
- instalar otras versiones de node js.
- volver a instalar semantic UI.
- cambiar el orden de los import.
- importar semantic y jquery desde CDN.

Comment: Hola Kenn, no es buea idea mezclar react con jquery, las dos librerías funcionan con principios diferentes y vas a tener más problemas que soluciones, tenés una versión de semanti ui para react, fijate si te sirve https://react.semantic-ui.com/

Comment: otro detalle más, estás importando solo los estilos de semantic, no la librería js que es la que tiene las funciones que necesitás

Comment: Muchas gracias!! leyendo un poco más entendí como se utilizan estos frameworks de css en React.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery es una biblioteca de manipulación DOM. Lee y escribe en el DOM. React utiliza un DOM virtual (una representación de JavaScript del DOM real). React solo escribe actualizaciones de parches en el DOM, pero nunca lee de él.
Aca esta la guia de Semantic para react, https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage. 
Solo tienes que instalar

```
npm i -S semantic-ui-react
```

y luego añadir los estilos a tu html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />
```